# Ormlite: foreign key with id

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using ormlite in my android project. I am trying to get the foreign key to work.
This is what I have for now.

I get json in the following structure and I need to save it to the database. For this I made the following object classes.

The first class I get is:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "gallery")
public class Gallery extends DatabaseModel {
public static final String FIELD_ID = "gal_id";
public static final String FIELD_TITLE = "gal_title";
public static final String FIELD_IMAGES = "gal_images";

//ID
@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_ID, id = true)
@SerializedName(FIELD_ID)
private int id;
//FIELDS
@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_TITLE)
@SerializedName(FIELD_TITLE)
private String title;
@ForeignCollectionField()
@SerializedName(FIELD_IMAGES)
private ForeignCollection<GalleryImage> images;

public Gallery() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String published) {
    this.title = title;
}

public ForeignCollection<GalleryImage> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(ForeignCollection<GalleryImage> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public void SaveAll(DataRepository repo, List<? extends DatabaseModel> models) {
    repo.galleryRepository.deleteAll();
    repo.galleryRepository.saveAll(repo, models);
}

@Override
public void Save(DataRepository repo) {
    repo.galleryRepository.create(this);
}
}
```

The second class is:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "galleryimages")
public class GalleryImage {
public static final String FIELD_ID = "pho_id";
public static final String FIELD_URL = "pho_url";
public static final String FIELD_GALLERY_ID = "pho_gal_id";

//ID
@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_ID, id = true)
@SerializedName(FIELD_ID)
private int id;
//FIELDS
@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_URL)
@SerializedName(FIELD_URL)
private String url;
@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_GALLERY_ID)
@SerializedName(FIELD_GALLERY_ID)
private int galleryId;

public GalleryImage() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String published) {
    this.url = url;
}

public int getGalleryId() {
    return galleryId;
}

public void setGalleryId(int galleryId) {
    this.galleryId = galleryId;
}
}
```

As you can see the ForeingCollection has more then one GalleryImage. And in the GalleryImage class I have an Id called: "pho_gal_id" that links back to the "gal_id" field.

This is the exception that I get when I run these two classes:

```
05-23 09:46:57.040    4613-4613/be.appmax.twentebad.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: be.appmax.twentebad.app, PID: 4613
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.appmax.twentebad.app/be.appmax.twentebad.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class be.appmax.twentebad.app.models.database.GalleryImage for field 'images' column-name does not contain a foreign field of class be.appmax.twentebad.app.models.database.Gallery
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class be.appmax.twentebad.app.models.database.GalleryImage for field 'images' column-name does not contain a foreign field of class be.appmax.twentebad.app.models.database.Gallery
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.database.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:70)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onCreate(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:66)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:54)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:243)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:196)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:118)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:241)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.database.repositories.MenuRepository.getAll(MenuRepository.java:87)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.MainActivity.readDatabase(MainActivity.java:103)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class be.appmax.twentebad.app.models.database.GalleryImage for field 'images' column-name does not contain a foreign field of class be.appmax.twentebad.app.models.database.Gallery
            at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.findForeignFieldType(FieldType.java:1020)
            at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:390)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:201)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.doCreateDao(DaoManager.java:359)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDaoFromConfig(DaoManager.java:326)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:55)
            at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:218)
            at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:53)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.database.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:65)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onCreate(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:66)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:54)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:243)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:196)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:118)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:241)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.database.repositories.MenuRepository.getAll(MenuRepository.java:87)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.MainActivity.readDatabase(MainActivity.java:103)
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Can somebody help me figure this out?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the inheritance myself and saving them both to two different databases.